# Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io/node_modules/redis' on Mac

Tags: django, node.js, macos, redis, socket.io

I am trying to run this example (http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/) but I'm getting this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io/node_modules/redis'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/felipemoran/Desktop/django-realtime-tutorial-master/nodejs/chat.js:7:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

What I did so far was:

- Unpack the source files - ok
- Start Redis server (by typing on terminal `redis-server`) - ok
- Start Django server (by typing on a different window `python manage.py runserver`, while in the propper folder) - ok

The next step would be, on a third terminal window, run the command `node chat.js`, while in the folder nodejs folder from the example files, but I'm getting this error.

I'm on Mac OS X Maverics, I installed node.js from the official mac installer and I installed socket.io using the npm command.

I also tried running `rpm install socket.io -g` , `rpm install -g socket.io`, those two with `sudo` and runing these commands from the nodejs folder but still no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `npm install socket.io` installs the latest version from [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io) which is now `1.1.0`. Your tutorial uses version `0.9` and a lot changed from that to `1.0`, including how to use the Redis adapter. Since the tutorial does not use a [package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html) to manage the dependencies you ended up with wrong version.

You can either upgrade your server code to work with latest `socket.io` (for which you need to install [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-redis)) or check the latest version from the `0.9` branch by running `npm view socket.io versions` and then install `npm install socket.io@0.9.17`.

And please remove the global installations, they will cause you gray hair later (`npm uninstall -g socket.io`).

Comment: Oh that must be why! Thank you so much!